# проблема с регулярными выражениями php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

здравствуйте!

есть регулярка:

```
        $patt = [ '~--([^-]+)--~', '~%%([^-]+)%%~'];
    $repl = ['<b>$1</b>', '<u>$1</u>];
```

которая меняет --такой текст-- на **жирный** и %%такой%% на подчеркнутый

но дело в том что если в строке есть символ "-", и возможно ещё какие то другие (я не успел проверить всё), то регулярное выражение не срабатывает, как можно это исправить? спасибо

Comment: Замените `[^-]+` на `.+?`

Answer (score 2):

@Mike вам в комментарии предложил заменить группы на [ленивый захват символов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF#.D0.96.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BA.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F), но можно поступить хитрее:
Для первого паттерна использовать такую [регулярку](https://regex101.com/r/1EWc1V/4)

```
~--([^-]+(-[^-]+)*)--~
```

Для второго - [такую](https://regex101.com/r/1EWc1V/5)

```
~%%([^%]+(%[^%]+)*)%%~
```

Нагрузка должна быть меньше, чем у ленивой квантификации.