# помогите составить шаблон регулярных выражений php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста сделать шаблон для регулярных выражений php,

мне нужно чтобы `**такой текст** превращался в <b>такой</b> и  __такой__ в <u>такой</u> и $$такой$$ в <green>такой</green>` и ещё несколько подобных образцов, которые я буду добавлять сам со временем

и нужно чтобы переносы строк так же учитывались, чтобы регулярка заменяла текст всегда, не смотря на то какие символы внутри него, и чтобы нельзя было юзать несколько форматирований сразу, тип из `**__текст__** получаем <b><u>текст</u></b>`

большое спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693444/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-php-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d1%8d%d0%b3%d0%b8

Comment: @Lexx918, больше похоже на этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692917/186083

Answer (score -1):

Здравствуйте. Используйте этот код:

```
    $search = array(
        "/__(.*?)__/",
        "/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/"
    );
    $replace = array(
        "<b>$1</b>",
        "<u>$1</u>"
    );
    $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
```

Comment: 1. `и нужно чтобы переносы строк так же учитывались, чтобы регулярка заменяла текст всегда, не смотря на то какие символы внутри него,` 2. `и чтобы нельзя было юзать несколько форматирований сразу, тип из **__текст__** получаем <b><u>текст</u></b>`.